# C# - List of objects, containing list of sub-objects

Tags: c#, database, performance, object

I have a question regarding on how to structure my code :

I want to display in 4 different ListView, list of objects.
Concretely, I have a list of Contract, each Contract contain a list of Subcontract, each Subcontracts has a list of assemblies, and each Assembly contain a list of Detail.
For Database I have no problem, I made a table for each Object, and they are linked by Id.

But until now, when I go from a ListView to another, I made a double-clic on my Contract, to display the ListView containing all its Subcontract. It also means a SQL request everytime.

I just got the idea to add in my Contract object, a property :

```
List<Subcontract> ListSubcontract {get;set;}
```

In my Subcontract object add property :

```
List<Assembly> ListAssemblies {get;set;}
```

Ans for Assembly :

```
List<Detail> ListDetails {get;set;}
```

I am just wondering in term of performance, is this a good thing to make so, because my Contract objects will have a list, of list, of list...

So regarding to you is this better to make a SQL query on every "double-clic" when I want to "navigate"? Or is this better to load "all at once my list of contracts, and then just navigate in my objects already built, updating only the ListCollections?

Thanks in advance for your advises

Comment: You could consider posting your code here for review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's worth noting that CR requires a concrete implementation. Pseudo or stub code will likely be closed

Comment: Excuse me, but which code concretely?

Comment: If you know your datasets are small, go ahead & load all at once. But if they could be of arbitraty size & scalabilty is a consideration, load-on-demand will scale better.

Comment: why don't you add them to the list rather making SQL call on every click event which will eat time.

Comment: in fact, they are not that big, maximum, for each contract will have 10 sub-contracts, 100 assemblies and 50 details...

Comment: Vicky S. this was the purpose of the question, I want to change all and just make a list of objects, but was afraid that making a "3 Levels list" will make the programm work slower, and ask more memory

Answer (score 0):

Start with the simplest and most flexible solution, when and if you detect performance issues, you can address them. And if round-trips to the database are expensive, there are various ways you can cache data to optimize it.  Having said that, if you know ahead of time you need to fetch a lot of data, minimising the number of queries is usually a good strategy.